# Oracle sqlldr loading multiple tables using a named pipe file

Tags: oracle, unix, sql-loader

I am moving data from DB2 UDB tables (several 100) to Oracle and for the majority of tables I will use sqlldr. The extracts from the DB2 tables were exported & compressed (using local AIX compress). I have fixed all data formats and I can load all tables using a sample snapshot. The problem is when I come to use the real size exports the file sizes mean I can not not uncompress them all at the same time (space limitations). I wanted to see if this is the best way to use a named pipe to save having to uncompress the files or should I have a named pipe file for each individual extract file?

```
mkfifo testUnzip
for tbl in `cat ./XXSchema_TblListing.rdr`
do nohup sqlldr userid=xxuser/pwd@dbname control=${tbl}.ctl.txt log=${tbl}results.log discard=${tbl}results.dsc direct=y data=testUnzip ERRORS=0 > ${tbl}run.out 2>&1 &
zcat ${tbl}.csv.Z  > testUnzip
done
```

----ADDED call in script for the following function. The problem I have is having sqlldr call return if a failure occurs. I have output in log file but as it does not return I can not return a fail to the initial call and then exit.

```
PROCESSLOAD(){
set -x
rm -f ${tblLoad}.log
echo "truncate table $USR.${tblLoad};" |   sqlplus  $USR/$PWD@dbase >> ./TblInfo.log
mkfifo ${tblLoad}.dat
nohup sqlldr userid=$USR/$PWD@dbase control=${tblLoad}.ctl.txt log=${tblLoad}_DESCresults.log direct=y data=${tblLoad}.dat >> ${tblLoad}.log 2>&1 &
Process_ID=$!
echo "${Process_ID}"
if [[ -z ${Process_ID} ]]; then
echo "Process Running";
fi
zcat ${tblLoad}.csv.Z > ${tblLoad}.dat
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then return 1
fi
```

Comment: Don't try to reuse the same pipe, especially if you want to process parallelly. Create a shell-function that processes one file/table (using named or unnamed pipe -- if named, the name of the pipe should contain the name of the table), and when that's working well, you can put it into a loop.

Comment: If you have `bash`, you can use process substitution, too: `cmd ... data=<(zcat $tbl.csv.Z)`

Comment: I will move the logic into a function and generate a named pipe to match the table name .. I tried to set the data arg data=<(zcat TEST.out.Z) but I get a syntax error: `(' unexpected (Korn Shell).

Comment: Sure, `bash` and `ksh` are different programs.

Comment: I added to a function and works.. The problem I have is when I force an error in sqlldr .. the process call is not returning for me to check if failed.  I updated the question with the new sample code to see if you could advise what I can do to check for sqlldr failing in background.